# Servlet as a J2EE client

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I was recently going through *head first servlet book* and came across the below line :

"**Servlet can be a J2EE client, while a Perl CGI program cannot**".

What does it mean by "Servlet can be a J2EE client"? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

It means that one can invoke any J2EE application from within a servlet.
However, the same is not true for a CGI program.